# Ruby error with mailgun on heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mailgun

I'm trying to make a 'contact us' page on a heroku server using mailgun. I am fairly confident I set it up right (I'm being spoon fed this project by following upskillcources.com), but I keep getting this error anyways "We're sorry, but something went wrong."
Here is the heroku logs that seem applicable to me:

2017-05-05T06:16:10.020320+00:00 app[web.1]:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"contacts"'::regclass
2017-05-05T06:16:10.020321+00:00 app[web.1]:                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2017-05-05T06:16:10.020322+00:00 app[web.1]:                ORDER BY a.attnum
2017-05-05T06:16:10.020323+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-05-05T06:16:10.020344+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-05-05T06:16:10.020309 #4] FATAL -- : [2777b122-a496-4a3d-b6b7-08b32fc56cd4]
2017-05-05T06:16:10.020377+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-05-05T06:16:10.020344 #4] FATAL -- : [2777b122-a496-4a3d-b6b7-08b32fc56cd4] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:3:in `new'

I have no idea what could be wrong with the code in the error logs, especially because I can see that the contacts_controller.rb file is identical to identical project codes found on the github's of multiple people using the same resource upskill resource.

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      name = params[:contact][:name]
      email = params[:contact][:email]
      body = params[:contact][:comments]
      ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Message sent."
       redirect_to new_contant_path #this should be contact path I think, but a c9 error suggested this instead and wouldn't work without the change dispite it being different than the codes on github for the same project.
    else
      flash[:danger] = @contact.errors.full_messages.join(", ")
       redirect_to new_contact_path
    end  
  end

  private
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end

end
```

Please also let me know for future ref how I can be better/more specific at asking questions here, so sorry for how difficult I am making it, this is my first programming project beyond 'hello world' and a to do app, thanks so much for taking the time!

Comment: Could you provide more lines of logs with this error? Full error message especially.

Comment: 2017-05-05T06:16:10.019684+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-05-05T06:16:10.019632 #4]  INFO -- : [2777b122-a496-4a3d-b6b7-08b32fc56cd4] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
2017-05-05T06:16:10.020262+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-05-05T06:16:10.020214 #4] FATAL -- : [2777b122-a496-4a3d-b6b7-08b32fc56cd4]   
2017-05-05T06:16:10.020312+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-05-05T06:16:10.020264 #4] FATAL -- : [2777b122-a496-4a3d-b6b7-08b32fc56cd4] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "contacts" does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logs says that you don't have a table in database.
You need to create and run migration. Details here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Also you need to remember that Heroku doesn't run migrations for your by default. So you will need to call `heroku run rake db:migrate` after deploying your code. But you can automate this process by adding release command to your Procfile. Detailed instruction here: http://aspiringwebdev.com/run-rails-migrations-automatically-on-heroku/

Comment: Thank you so so so much! You were spot on with the problem and solution!

Comment: @Shem glad to help. Could you mark the answer as solution for your question?

Comment: Sorry about that! This was my first post